# deactivated_plugin hook: get the name of the plugin

Tags: hooks, deactivated-plugin

I would like that every time any plugin previously activated, a function from my plugin be called, returning (at least) the name of the plugin, or something that allows to identify it (file name?).

I figured i could use the action hook "deactivated_plugin" but i'm wondering what information from the desactivated plugin is actually available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook into the action `'deactivate_plugin'` to get the plugin's base name and (as second parameter) if it was deactivated network wide.

See `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php function deactivate_plugins()`.

There seems to be no hook for plugin deletion.

Sample logging code:

```
add_action( 'activated_plugin', 't5_plugin_logger', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'deactivated_plugin', 't5_plugin_logger', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Log plugin activations and deactivations.
 *
 * @param  string $plugin
 * @param  bool   $network_wide
 * @return void
 */
function t5_plugin_logger( $plugin, $network_wide )
{
    $log_size = 20;
    $log      = get_option( 't5_plugin_log', array () );

    // Remove the oldest entry.
    sizeof( $log ) > $log_size and array_shift( $log );

    $plugin_data = get_plugin_data( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . $plugin );
    $date_format = get_option( 'date_format' ) . ' · ' . get_option( 'time_format' );

    $log[] = array (
        'user'    => esc_html( wp_get_current_user()->display_name ),
        'plugin'  => $plugin_data['Name'],
        'network' => $network_wide ? '✔' : '',
        'time'    => date( $date_format, time() ),
        'action'  => 'deactivated_plugin' === current_filter() ? 'deactivated' : 'activated'
    );

    update_option( 't5_plugin_log', $log );
}
```

Now every plugin activation or deactivation will be added to the log option field. You can use this data anywhere. I made a small dashboard widget:

[image]

Download as plugin from GitHub: [T5 Plugin Log](https://gist.github.com/2802082)

Comment: thanks for that. I think what i'm trying to do is impossible: i need my function to be called whenever _any_ plugin is deactivated, not just mine.

Comment: @pixeline See my update, I have added some sample code.

Comment: @toscho wow, amazing. Thank you for putting so much time into this. I'm building a plugin that will take care of plugins but also for themes and WPcore changes. If you are interested, maybe we partner up?

Comment: Yeah, would be cool. :) There is also an old plugin [Last Edits](https://github.com/toscho/Last-Edits.-WordPress-Dashboard-Widget) which I wanted to refresh and extend for … years. Tracking system changes would be enough for a start, I'm also interested in changes to PHP, MySQL and Apache because web hoster do this usually rather silent.

Comment: good point. Note that i started writing my plugin as a class. Also, it uses a custom db table for the logging, not the wp option system, because i figured there would be a lot of data at some point.

Comment: Ok, i've got it working in my class, and i've also added the logging of all options changed. Toscho you got me really on the tracks, so i'll credit you in the plugin and send you the link to the wordpress svn repository so if you feel like contributing (with the core apache logging for instance) go ahead!

Comment: Toscho, version 1 is available here. Thanks again!  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-changes-tracker/